# Test for divergence of the integal $\int_0^\infty |x|^a/(x+b)^{c+1} dx$ if $a<c$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Prove that this integral is less than infinity. If $0<a<c$ and $0<b$: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{|x|^a}{(x+b)^{c+1}} dx.$$

From inspection, because $a<c$ and $|x| < |x+b|$, if this I was looking at the absolute convergence, then the numerator is smaller than the denominator, so it would converge. But, I am not used to trying to find convergence of integrals, I am used to series.

I tried doing integration by parts and substituting the original integral back in, but that did not work. I can show that here if someone wants to see.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Is your $ b>0$ ?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah yes, I will put that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that since $b > 0$, the $\int_0^\infty \frac{|x|^a}{(x+b)^{c+1}} dx < \int_0^\infty \frac{|x + b|^a}{(x+b)^{c+1}} dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+b)^{c - a+1}} dx$. Now, since $c > a$, the last one obviously converges.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Near $ +\infty $, the integrand function satisfies

$$\frac{x^a}{(x+b)^{c+1}}\sim \frac{1}{x^{c+1-a}}$$

So, if

$$c+1-a>1$$
or
$$a<c,$$

it will converge.